# Notepad ++ extract MAC addresses from text

Tags: notepad++, regex, mac-address, extract

How to extract MAC addresses from text to get a list where each line is one MAC adress only?
I try to mark MAC addresses with regex, bookmark lines and delete unmarked lines but there is still too much text around.

Here is regex that I use:

```
((([a-zA-z0-9]{2}[-:]){5}([a-zA-z0-9]{2}))|(([a-zA-z0-9]{2}:){5}([a-zA-z0-9]{2})))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since hexadecimal doesn't use letters after f you could change the RE accordingly. `[A-Fa-f0-9]`

If you want lines that contain no other text on the line, use `^` and `$` to indicate start and end of line.

Your second subexpression seems to be a subset of the first and redundant.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `.*?(?<![-:a-f\d])(?|([a-f\d]{2}(?::[a-f\d]{2}){5})|([a-f\d]{2}(?:-[a-f\d]{2}){5}))(?![-:a-f\d]).*?`
- Replace with: `$1\n`
- **UNCHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **CHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
.*?             # 0 or more any character, not greedy
(?<![-:a-f\d])  # negative lookbehind, make sure we haven't hyphen, colon or hex before
(?|             # branch reset group
    (               # group 1
        [a-f\d]{2}      # 2 characters in range a-fA-F0-9
        (?:             # non capture group
            :               # colon
            [a-f\d]{2}      # 2 characters in range a-fA-F0-9
        ){5}            # end group, must appear 5 times
    )               # end group 1
|               # OR
    (               # group 1
        [a-f\d]{2}      # 2 characters in range a-fA-F0-9
        (?:             # non capture group
            -               # hyphen
            [a-f\d]{2}      # 2 characters in range a-fA-F0-9
        ){5}            # end group, must appear 5 times
    )               # end group 1
)               # end branch reset group
(?![-:a-f\d])   # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't hyphen, colon or hex after
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1      # content of group 1 (i.e. the mac address)
\n      # linefeed, you can use \r\n for windows eol
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: This allows mixing delimiters, so will match for example `3D-F2-C9:A6-B3:4F`.

Comment: @harrymc: True, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This regex will enforce the usage of delimiters, so will not match a mix of
`-` and `:` delimiters (such as for `3D-F2-C9:A6-B3:4F`):

```
(?:[[:xdigit:]]{2}([-:]))(?:[[:xdigit:]]{2}\1){4}[[:xdigit:]]{2}
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260467/what-is-a-regular-expression-for-a-mac-address)