# How can I use a regex to keep MAC addresses and delete everything else in a string?

Tags: notepad++, regex

What regular expression would I need to delete everything except for the macs which can include the letters `A-F` (in capitals) and digits `0-9`

I want to delete everything else (letters and numbers) and other characters (`-,!,?,@ etc`).

I just want to keep the MAC address. For example:

```
text 1 here
text: example 1
text- ??????
1F:F2:C9:A6:B3:4F

text 2 here
text: example 2
text- ??????!!!@@@
3D:F2:D9:F3:C3:A1


text 3 here
text: example 3
text- ??????!!!@@@
E8:F2:D9:A6:A3:11
```

I want the following result (each mac address on a new line):-

```
1F:F2:C9:A6:B3:4F
3D:F2:D9:F3:C3:A1
E8:F2:D9:A6:A3:11
```

Comment: What about [`^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})$`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4260512) as shown on this Stack Overflow answer here.

Comment: That just highlights the mac address, it does't delete the other data?

Comment: Well, I guess now you can figure out how to tell Notepad to do the opposite. Match everything else and delete that.

Comment: Help me out please, I'm still new to all this...

Comment: I did! I linked to a similar answer on Stack Overflow and gave you a place to start. I cannot provide an answer because I am on macOS and unclear on how Notepad++ works, but maybe someone else can come along and help you out more.

Comment: Are the MAC addresses **alone** in a line?

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/1632529/763386

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work too:

```
(?is).*?(([A-F\d]{2})(?:[:-][A-F\d]{2}){5})|.+
```

Replace with: `\1\n`

Comment: This matching string with a mix of separators `:` & `-` that is not allowed in a MAC address

Comment: Generally, it's true. However, I cannot think of a setting where I would actually run into a mixed version AND in such uber rare occasion I would not want it to be matched.

Comment: Thanks guys, that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly try:

```
(?i).*?^([0-9A-F]{2}([:-])(?:[0-9A-F]{2}\2){4}[0-9A-F]{2})$
```

Replace with `\1\n`

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/JqyG9E/1). You'll have a trailing empty newline though. Make sure you tick ". matches newline" (see screenshot below).

[image]